# How to create a soundfile with Timidity++ specifying a particular soundfont sf2 file?

Tags: midi, soundfont

I have a midi file `scale.mid` that I can play via

```
timidity my-midi-file.mid -Ow
```

How can I play this using the instruments of my own soundfont `.sf2` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timidity` can accept a configuration parameter using the option `-x` i.e. `--config-string`. In this case:

```
timidity my-midi-file.mid --config-string="soundfont my-soundfont-file.sf2"
```

From the `timidity` man file:

> -x str, --config-string=str
>
> Configure TiMidity++ with str.  The format of str is the same as timidity.cfg.